# Asynchronous programming with custom DTO's and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Hopefully I can explain myself clearly, as I'm fairly new to `async/await` and `Task`.

Basically I'm going down the route of teaching myself asynchronous programming, whilst fundamentally, I fully understand the concept, and when it's best applied.

Although in my project, I may have gone a little *overboard*. So I've always enjoyed crafting my own DTO's, and I don't really enjoy using a third party tool (AutoMapper) to do so, But potentially with great regret because I'm not really sure how to return `Task<DTO>` from manually mapping.

If I may elaborate:

**Client Repo**

```
public sealed class ClientRepository : IClientRepository
{
    private ClientConfigEntities _context;

    public ClientRepository(ClientConfigEntities context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task<Client> AuthenticateAsync(string apiKey, string password)
    {
       //Throws error because it cannot return Task<Client> from Client
        return await MapClient.ToModel(_context.tbl_Client
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ApiKey == apiKey
                        && c.Password == password));

    }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
public static class MapClient
{
    public static Client ToModel(tbl_Client source)
    {
        return (source != null) ? new Client
        {
            Id = source.Id,
            ApiKey = source.ApiKey,
            ApiURL = source.ApiURL,
            ClientKey = source.ClientKey,
            Password = source.Password,
            RetainMeApiKey = source.RetainMeApiKey,
            Secret = source.Secret
        }
        : null;
    }
}
```

I also have another abstraction `AuthenticationService` which is then called in a `Controller` - allows me to hide complexity.

With the above I've tried return a `Task<Client>` on the `static` mapping method but I'm sure as your aware of, it throws type issues.

What's the best approach to return an asynchronous `Task<Client>?`

Really hope someone can give me insight into how and why?

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention on what `FirstOrDefaultAsync` return: `Task<Client>`. Then you are trying to pass this Task to a method that accept a Client object and not a `Task<Client>`.
Change as follow:

```
return MapClient.ToModel(await _context.tbl_Client
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ApiKey == apiKey
                            && c.Password == password));
```

By doing this `await _context.tbl_Client.FirstOrDefaultAsync` will return a Client object once the Task is completed and after that you will pass the model into your mapping method (I also suggest you to use the [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) instead of a "normal" static method).

Comment: Thank you for your help, +1 for the extension method tip.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Tinwor's answer, there was some confusion in OP in where the await was to be used. Trying to do the desired code inline helped in causing that confusion.

Refactor the code to make it easier to read and identify where awaited code should be placed thus showing the intent of the code.

```
public async Task<Client> AuthenticateAsync(string apiKey, string password) {
    var entity = await _context.tbl_Client.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
        c => c.ApiKey == apiKey && c.Password == password
    );
    var model = MapClient.ToModel(entity);
    return model;
}
```

Converting the `ToModel` to an extension method also allows the code to be cleaner as well

```
public static class MapClient {
    public static Client ToModel(this tbl_Client source) {
        return (source != null) ? new Client {
            Id = source.Id,
            ApiKey = source.ApiKey,
            ApiURL = source.ApiURL,
            ClientKey = source.ClientKey,
            Password = source.Password,
            RetainMeApiKey = source.RetainMeApiKey,
            Secret = source.Secret
        }
        : null;
    }
}
```

Which would result in the final code looking like

```
public async Task<Client> AuthenticateAsync(string apiKey, string password) {
    var entity = await _context.tbl_Client.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
        c => c.ApiKey == apiKey && c.Password == password
    );
    var model = entity.ToModel();// <-- extension method used here
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help, As with the first answer... Extension method certainly helps keeping the code... Thanks for your time. I may spend a little more time with asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

First, MapClient.ToModel is not a async method. So you cannot call await on this method.
Second, you are only mapping the data within the ToModel method. So there is no need to make it async either.
The best way to handle this would be to change the return type of 'AuthenticateAsync' method to Client only(not compulsary though). The code inside the method can be changed to -

```
return MapClient.ToModel(await _context.tbl_Client.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
        c => c.ApiKey == apiKey && c.Password == password
    ));
```

Comment: I fully understand that it's not an async method , just by looking at the signature. Thanks for your time.